# Google Assistant not working across languages

Tags: settings, languages, accessibility, google-assistant

I am running Google Assistant on Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G phone.

I have both English and Italian configured as languages in Settings.

When I issue the command "Open Settings" the Settings app opens up.

But, on the other hand, when I issue the "Apri impostazioni" command in Italian which literally translates to "open settings" Google Assistant talks back to me telling me what to do with a set of given instructions on how to open the settings app (it does not open it for me automatically). At the same time, it displays the following text:

- "Un attimo" (Just a moment)
- "Operazione in corso" (operation being carried out)
- "Operazione ancora in corso" (operation still being carried out)
- "Ci siamo quasi" (we're almost there)

Google Assistant then stalls, almost as though in a long process (and the settings app never automatically opens up).

This would be important for me, as I am trying to assess the usability of Android, and in particular of Google Assistant, for blind (and visually impaired) users.

Why doesn't the corrisponding command in Italian just open the settings app?

Thanks.